# ¿Como puedo llenar un progres bar?

Tags: jquery

¿Como puedo llenar un progres bar conforme vaya seleccionando un radio button? cabe mencionar que son grupos de radio los cuales se crean de manera dinámica.

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Realiza el recorrido del tour https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla 2. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que intentastes? Por otro lado piensa en la logica, si por ejemplo tienes 10 `radio-buttons`, entonces podrias crear una variable con valor 0 para que cuando se vallan seleccionando mas `radio-buttons` esta incremente +1(Para llegar al valor maximo que es 10) y cada vez que lo haga el `progres bar` aumente

Answer (score 0):

Pues de manera abstracta te podrias decir lo siguiente:

El progressbar tiene un valor mínimo y un valor máximo, dependiendo de lo que esté haciendo, asignale a cada radio un valor para aumente el progressbar.